# Disable sending a chatter message which is sent to all users when sharing a file

Tags: email, chatter, upload, chatter-file

I wrote a trigger on FeedItem to share a file. Salesforce automitcally sends a chatter message when sharing a file.
Is it possible to disable sending a chatter message and an email which is sent to all users when sharing a file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you currently sharing a file by creating a feed post on another entity?  If so, an alternative is to insert a ContentDocumentLink to the entity (which happens when a feed post is made).